# Verilog to schematic block

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, verilog

Is there any tool in linux that converts VHDL/Verilog code to an equivalent schematic block?

I know the available tools:

```
* Synplicity
* Synopsys Design Compiler
* Altera Quartus II
* Xilinx ISE
```

But these are not free.

Comment: This question extends on [this one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/how-can-i-generate-a-schematic-block-diagram-image-file-from-verilog). I propose to merge.

Comment: @stevenvh - This question focuses on free tools which must run on Linux, while that one makes no distinctions as to cost or platform.  These questions are clearly related, and could even possibly be closed as duplicates (if the community decides that we don't need software questions which make these distinctions), but the requirements for merging are still more stringent.

Comment: @raj - Are you looking for tools which are free as in beer, or free as in speech?

Answer (score 2):

The free Quartus II Web Edition software can do that. I think that the free Xilinx ISE can, as well. They run under Linux.

Comment: yes, but is there one that comes with no expiry date

Comment: There isn't a time limit for the current versions. One used to have to renew the license for the Xilinx IDE

Comment: There isn't a time limit, now. One had to renew the license every six months for the Altera tools at one time, but not any more.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at tools at http://opencircuitdesign.com/ everything there is open source and free (mostly). I think XCircuit is the software you are looking for http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/index.html. I myself only check functionality (through simulation) and verify synthesis results so I've never tried XCircuit myself.

If you want to follow complete EDA flow (compile to PnR - maybe even beyond) read http://opencircuitdesign.com/verilog/index.html, in that post all required stuff is mentioned.

If you can't find libraries then look for OSU libraries they are free and can support upto 18micron (I tried 25 micron so not sure about 18).

Apart from these iverilog is really neat compiler. And Emacs code browser is a good editor.

Hope it answers your question.