# How can I generate a circuit image from VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, logic-gates

I've seen this question: [How can I generate a schematic block diagram image file from verilog?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/how-can-i-generate-a-schematic-block-diagram-image-file-from-verilog?newreg=340023559e2743c5ba6afbbbd091cc76), but it talks about verilog, not VHDL. Some answers to that question mention paid tools, and I'm looking exclusively for free, non-commercial tools.

I would like the process to be completely automatic and not manual. I would also like the image to consist purely of logic gates. I've tried researching but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: *" I would also like the image to consist purely of logic gates. "* I think you need a synthesis tools. All the tools I know which make images from code, use 'behavioral blocks  like ADD, SUB, MULT etc. .

Comment: ISE can do this but I have to look back to see how I did it since it's a fairly useless feature. It's only good for showing my boss a pretty picture, and all it does is create a block diagram of the modules with the connections in between. No logic gates if you did not code it as logic gates.

Comment: use quartus or vivado for nice block diagram and schematic generation

Comment: For schematics, the only time that I have seen this to be marginally useful is when we were transitioning from schematic based ASICs to VHDL ASICs and had a hybrid of the two. Gate level schematics generated from VHDL are really, really, hard to understand. So, unless you have a really good reason to do this, I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is a two-step process:

- Convert HDL to a netlist (a logical description of connectivity)
- Convert a netlist into a diagram.

HDL (whether that's Verilog or VHDL) to netlist can only be done by a synthesis tool. While there are a few "free" synthesis tools, mostly for specialized applications, most are tied to specific technology vendors.

While converting a schematic to a netlist is fairly straightforward (most any schematic-capture software can produce netlists in a number of formats), converting a netlist into a usable diagram is a hard problem, and I have yet to see a tool, free or otherwise, that does a decent job.

And in the end, such automatically-generated diagrams are rarely useful for any real work anyway.