# Drawing a Visual Hardware Representation for VHDL Code

Tags: vhdl

The following code is given. My task involves drawing a visual hardware representation that outlines the modules, their associated ports, and the interconnecting signals. Check out my solution below. Am I on the right track?

**`flipflop.vhdl`**:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Clocked_Logic is

    port (i_Clk      : in  std_logic;
          i_Switch_1 : in  std_logic;
          o_LED_1    : out std_logic);
    
end entity Clocked_Logic;


architecture RTL of Clocked_Logic is

    signal r_Switch_1 : std_logic := '0';
    signal r_LED_1    : std_logic := '0';

    begin
        
        -- this clocked-sequential process starts when i_Clk state change
        -- the sensitivity list contains only i_Clk
        p_Register: process (i_Clk) is
        begin

            if rising_edge(i_Clk) then

                r_Switch_1 <= i_Switch_1;
                    
                if i_Switch_1  = '0' and r_Switch_1 = '1' then 
                    
                    r_LED_1 <= not r_LED_1;
                        
                end if; 
                                        
            end if;
                
        end process p_Register;
            
        o_LED_1 <= r_LED_1;
    
end architecture RTL;
```

**My solution:**

[image]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/how-can-i-generate-a-schematic-block-diagram-image-file-from-verilog/269121 <-- the same from verilog. You can possibly read simple VHDL nowadays directly with yosys, or you can convert using `ghdl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design has 2 flipflops. The first flipflop is needed to store r_switch_1. The second flipflop is needed to store r_LED_1. The second flipflop will toogle as soon as there is a falling edge at i_Switch_1. A toogle flipflop can be build by a multiplexer which leads the q-output of the flipflop back to the d-input of the flipflop, in one case as a inverted signal and in the other case as a not inverted signal. This results in a schematic like this:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. Which tool are you using? Best Regards

Comment: [HDL-SCHEM-Editor](http://www.hdl-schem-editor.de)

Comment: Tanks a lot. Does the symbol `<=` from the line `r_Switch_1 <= i_Switch_1;` means a register? So with this line I am creating a flipflop right?

Comment: Yes, this line creates a flipflop. If the statement which includes '<=' is inside a process which checks for a rising clock edge, then you will get a flipflop.

Comment: by the way here the Final Design Statistics:
    Number of LUTs       :   2,
    Number of DFFs       : 2,
    Number of DFFs packed to IO : 0,
    Number of Carrys     : 0,
    Number of RAMs       : 0,
    Number of ROMs       : 0,
    Number of IOs        : 2,
    Number of GBIOs      : 1,
    Number of GBs        : 0,
    Number of WarmBoot   : 0,
    Number of PLLs       : 0

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not totally correct. Your code is not only a DFF.
Your p_Register process also has some logic.

It seems that it needs r_switch_1 to perform a "AND" with i_switch_1, so the process needs both signals as inputs. Also inside the if, the process needs to know the logic state of r_LED_1. So it is a input of your process as well.

That means that r_switch_1 and r_LED_1 need to loopback to the p_Register process.

[image]

Comment: Tanks a lot. Does the symbol `<=` from the line `r_Switch_1 <= i_Switch_1;` means a register? So with this line I am creating a flipflop right?

Comment: Yes that line synchronize the input signal with the clock, it is a DFF. The schematic proposed is the outside representation of your module. In reality the hardware description of p_Register will contain at least one DFF.